# How to test Patch request?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'm trying to do a unit test on my angular project, and I faced with a problem, that I have no idea how to test patch request, any idea how to do it?

Thank you in advance!

Here is my patch request in profile.service.ts

```
patch(userModel: Owner): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.patch(ApiUrls.profile, userModel).pipe(
      tap((data: any) => {
        this.sessionService.user = data;
        this.profile$.next(data);
      }));
  }
```

and Owner model

```
export class Owner {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  email: string;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  avatar: string;
  location: string;
  color_scheme: string;
  language: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is good read from Angular Docs about testing http calls: https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests

Basically it consists of three steps. First you need to import `HttpTestingController` in your `TestBed` and extract `HttpClient` from injector that will be needed for making requests and `HttpTestingController` that is needed to verify and process requests.

Next in your test you need to invoke method making httpCall

```
yourServiceInstance.patch(testData)
  .subscribe(response =>
    // here you can assert response
    expect(response).toEqual(expectedResponse);
  );
```

than in same test get handle of `HttpTestingController` and assert that request that you just set up was executed, also we will grab handler for this request

```
const requestHandler = httpTestingController.expectOne(ApiUrls.profile);
```

With this `requestHandler` you can assert some additional things like you your case that method is PATCH

```
expect(requestHandler.request.method).toEqual('PATCH');
```

Finally you have to flush request in `requestHandler` so with `expectedResponse` that will be asserted in subscribe that was set up above and we call `verify()` on `HttpTestingController` to ensure no unexpected request happened in meantime.

```
requestHandler.flush(expectedResponse);
httpTestingController.verify();
```